# Regular expression check if string contain

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression. In order to check if a given string contains only `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` and a set of this char: `.,|$_`.

In addition I need also a regex to check if the string contains at least one char for each of these 4 groups.

I'm working on PHP but I think regex are generic.

Comment: And I need money. Life's hard. (have you tried anything? Have you googled?)

Comment: http://de2.php.net/preg_match this might help you, there are many examples. If you do not understand what a regex does: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=\d%2B%28.\d%2B%29%3F%28[eE]\d%2B%29%3F

Comment: At least provide examples of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code. and try this.

```
$var = "stackoverflow";

if(preg_match('/[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|[.,$_]/', $var)) {
    echo "Matched";
}
else {
    echo "do not match";
}
```

That's it.

Thanks.

Comment: ...and for the "at least one of each category" requirement it's easy to add 4 separate checks

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "stackoverflow";

if( (preg_match('/[A-Z]{1}/', $var) &&
     preg_match('/[a-z]{1}/', $var) &&
     preg_match('/[0-9]{1}/', $var) &&
     preg_match('/[.,$_]{1}/', $var)) ) {
    echo "String matches and contains at least one character from each group.";
}
elseif(preg_match('/[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|[.,$_]/', $var)) {
    echo "String matches, but doesn't contain characters from all four groups.";
}
else {
    echo "String does not match.";
}
```

Comment: gr8. I was looking how to identify each as a separate group that contains at least one character. good work.